# delete all rows and insert data from an external api to sql db every hour in laravel-nova (using laravel task scheduler)

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

[callapi file (command file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/687gH.png)i am new to php and got an assignment in laravel nova.
i need to update my database every hour. I've manged to do it manually but i cant seem to make it work in laravel task scheduler. this is the appropriate files (i hope). thanks in advance for the answers.
1.i created a new command
2. i add the command logic
3. i set the command to run every minute (for testing) in kernel.php
4. i ran php artisan schedule:run.

no response!
[kernel.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/843Ml.png)
[command shows on php artisan list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHb7R.png)

Comment: When you run the command manually to update the database everything works fine?

Comment: I get this error massage
 ErrorException

  Object of class Illuminate\View\View could not be converted to int

Comment: Why are you returning a view?

Comment: just to see if its changes, i removed it and now it doesn't do anything, and the error msg is gone

Comment: should i return something, or i can leave it without a return? i appreciate the help!

Comment: You can leave it without